VBA Help in Excel
How do I write a VBA that will give me the ranges for zip codes based on the following:



Column A
Column B




00210
1


00544
1


00548
2


00840
3


01101
1


01200
2



Needed result



Column A
Column B




00210-00547
1


00548-00839
2


00840-01100
3


01101-01199
1



A wonderful human gave me the below but it's doing a new row for every zip and I need it to do only a new row if the zone number changes.
Sub try_this()
    Dim y As Long, lastrow As Long, sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("put_your_sheet_name_here") 'change this
    'get last row
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 1 To lastrow - 1
        With sht.Cells(y, 1)
            'create range in 3rd column
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = .Value & "-" & .Offset(1, 0).Value - 1
            'copy range name to 4th column
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
        End With
    Next
End Sub


Please edit your question to show what you have tried, and where you had a problem. And why VBA? You could do this with formulas or Power Query also.

The VBA above is what I tried. If you know how it could be done another way, I'm all ears.

What I'm confused on is the 2nd instance of 1 on the second table. Is this a mistake?

No.  That's where a new zip code has a new zone of 1.  I am taking 44,000 us zip codes who might have different zones based on zip codes and the ranges won't have an exact repeat. In this instance the next row would be 01200-x is zone 2.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
//Assumes zip codes are entered as text strings
//   if they are formatted numbers, some changes will be required
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ZipZones"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Zip", type text}, {"Zone", Int64.Type}}),

//Group by Zone, but using GroupKind.Local to group by each change of zone
//  and return the minimum Zip code in each zone
//  Assumes zip codes are sorted ascending within each zone as you show.
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Zone"}, {{"Range", each List.Min([Zip]), type nullable text}},GroupKind.Local),
    
//Create and add the Zip Range for each Zone
    #"Add Zip Range" = Table.FromColumns(
        let 
            zipRange = List.Generate(
                ()=>[z=#"Grouped Rows"[Range]{0} & Number.ToText(Number.From(#"Grouped Rows"[Range]{1}) - 1,"-00000"), idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(#"Grouped Rows")-1,
                each [z=#"Grouped Rows"[Range]{[idx]+1} & Number.ToText(Number.From(#"Grouped Rows"[Range]{[idx]+2}) - 1,"-00000"), idx=[idx]+1],
                each [z]),
            zone = List.RemoveLastN(#"Grouped Rows"[Zone],1) 
        in 
            {zipRange} & {zone}, type table[Range=text, Zone=Int64.Type])
in
    #"Add Zip Range"



My proposal with VBA code. Data are read from Worksheets(1), results are placed in Worksheets(2).
Sub try_new()
    Dim y As Long, lastrow As Long, sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)  ' Worksheets("put_your_sheet_name_here")
    'get last row
    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim coll As New Collection, addok As Boolean
    For y = 1 To lastrow
        'verify next zone number
        addok = False
        If y = 1 Then
            addok = True
        ElseIf sht.Cells(y, 2).Value <> sht.Cells(y - 1, 2).Value Then
            addok = True
        End If
        If addok Then
            'add to collection
            coll.Add sht.Cells(y, 1).Resize(, 2).Value
        End If
    Next y
    
    'read the collection and produce results
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = Worksheets(2)
    sht2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear
    For y = 1 To coll.Count - 1
        'create range in columns A:B of sht2
        sht2.Cells(y, 1).Value = coll(y)(1, 1) & " - " & Format(coll(y + 1)(1, 1) - 1, "00000")
        sht2.Cells(y, 2).Value = coll(y)(1, 2)
    Next y
End Sub


Here is one another way to accomplish the desired output using Excel Formulas, applicable to MS365:


=LET(
     _Data, A2:B7,
     _Zip, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Zone, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _NZone, SCAN(0,_Zone=DROP(VSTACK("",_Zone),-1),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c,r,r+1))),
     _SZip, XLOOKUP(_NZone,_NZone,_Zip),
     _EZip, INDEX(_Zip,XMATCH(XLOOKUP(_NZone,_NZone,_Zip,,,-1),_Zip)+1)-1,
     UNIQUE(DROP(HSTACK(TOCOL(BYROW(HSTACK(_SZip,_EZip),LAMBDA(x, 
     TEXTJOIN("-",,BASE(x,10,5)))),2),_Zone),-1)))


